# Get past chain data in contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethers.js, history

So I know you can fetch past chain data in ethers.js by doing something like this:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenContractAddress, genericErc20Abi, signer);
const balance = await contract.balanceOf(address, { blockTag: blockHeightToBeUsedToFetchData });
```

where it is crucial to provide the blockTag with whatever block you want data from. And of course you need to use a full archive RPC.

Is it possible to do something like this inside a contract? So something like:

```
function fetchPastBalance(uint256 historicalBlock) public view returns(uint256){
   return IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(msg.sender, { magicOverrideStuff: historicalBlock });
}
```

If so, how would it actually be done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you store the information in the contract it is not possible. The only historical available data if the most recent 255 block ids.

Comment: that was what I expected but just wanted to make sure, thanks